# Error while trying to load tensorflowJS model from local, Fetch API cannot load downloads://model. URL scheme must be"https" for CORS request error

Tags: google-chrome, tensorflow.js

I am trying to load a tensorflow js model that is saved in downloads directory as mentioned in the tutorials of tensorflowjs. But I am facing cors error please find the image below.

Code:

```
<html>

<head>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>

<script>

async function app() {

const t = await tf.loadLayersModel('downloads://model');
console.log("done");
console.log(t);
}

app();


</script>
<script>

</script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Any pointers on how to resolve this.

Tried disabling cors for chrome but still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol you specified looks invalid. You can specify `file://` or just omitting it should work. And also you need to specify the path to `model.json` file created by [tfjs-converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter). So overall, the code to load the model may look like this.

```js
const t = await tf.loadLayersModel('file:///path/to/downloads/model.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fetch API cannot load downloads://model. URL scheme must be“https” for CORS request error

The error says it all. According to the official docs, here is what we can read for the url parameter

> A string path to the ModelAndWeightsConfig JSON describing the model in the canonical TensorFlow.js format. For file:// (tfjs-node-only), http:// and https:// schemas, the path can be either absolute or relative.

`download` does not mean anything, at least not when loading a model. It is instead used when downloading the model to the file system.

Therefore, if you're loading your model in the browser, consider first serving your model by a server and use a syntax like

```
const t = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://path/to/downloads/model.json'); // it can also be https if the server has a ssl certificate
```

If working in a nodejs server environment, then the file can be accessed directly using `file` identifier

```
const t = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://path/to/downloads/model.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue when I was doing my Coursera assignment.

The problem was not exactly with the tensorflow.js.

I solved the problem by pointing the CSV directly to github URL like

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...../...../testingdata.csv

instead of putting them in my own laptop directories.

Then it should work.